# How to set optional parameter in REST API's mongolab?

Tags: restful-url, mlab

I need to use upsert() for an update. The request url is shown below.

https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/col+"?q={}&u=true&apiKey=key

It results 500 Internal Server Error. Without u=true the url works fine.

Thank you in advance

======== UPDATE =========

Current Solution. I send two requests. If the update request does not find any specified document, return 0, it will send another request for insert. This approach is quite expensive. Looking forward for better solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since you got an Internal Server Error you should probably contact MongoLab Support at support@mongolab.com so we can identify your specific account and go through the logs to identify the problem.

For your reference, here are our docs on updates and upserts via the RESTful Data API: http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#update-documents

Some initial thoughts, not having all the information: You don't specify the HTTP method you're using. For upserts (or any update) you'll need to use PUT. Also, updates assume there's a replacement doc or update modifiers in the body of the request.

Cheers!

Jared

Comment: Thank for reply. I specified PUT and the body on the request. I will try to contact MongoLab support.